# Хостер на первое время

Tags: хостинг

Какой бы вы посоветовали **бесплатный** хостер на первое время, с поддержкой mysql и php а так же движков типо этого:

```
<?php
include ('/core.php');
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'default';
switch ($page) {
   case ('register'):
        include ('/style/register.php');   
        break;
   default :
        include ('/style/main.php');
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Движок, гы)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tut.su, ovl.ru, bplaced.net, 000webhost.com - просто введи в поисковике и тестируй всех подряд - всё равно везде будут траблы...

Мой совет - начни например с http://hostia.ru/ ~340 рублей в год это копейки

--
P.S. так и хочется реф.ссылку поставить :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [этот](http://webhost1.ru/?r=936) он не совсем бесплатный, но цены низкие, и есть первая тестовая неделя - бесплатно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, раз пошла такая пьянка, тогда и я подкину [ссылочку](http://kubez.biz) - тарифы от 20 рублей в месяц + хорошие отзывы на [хостобзоре](http://hostobzor.ru/), да и сам пользуюсь. Тех. поддержка работает оперативно.

Если совсем бесплатно, то поддержу korwru - tut.su - не плох.